# How to retrieve data from cassandra using IN Query with given order?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I'm selecting data from a Cassandra database using a query. It is working fine but how to get the data in same order as I have given IN query?

I have created table like this:

```
 id | n | p | q
----+---+---+------
  5 | 1 | 2 |    4
 10 | 2 | 4 |    3
 11 | 1 | 2 | null
```

I am trying to select data using

```
SELECT * 
FROM malleshdmy 
WHERE id IN ( 11,10,5)
```

But, It producing same data as like stored.

```
 id | n | p | q
----+---+---+------
  5 | 1 | 2 |    4
 10 | 2 | 4 |    3
 11 | 1 | 2 | null
```

Please help me in this issue.

I want data as 11,10 and 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `id` is partition key, then it's impossible - data are sorted only inside the clustering columns, and data for different partition keys could be returned in arbitrary order (but sorted inside that partition).

You need to sort data yourself.

Comment: To add to this, if the data size in your table gets large then even if it were possible you'd be sorting all the data set on the coordinator and run into performance issues. As the above answer states, you're better off sorting at the application end

Comment: Yes, that's true!

Answer (score 1):

Since id is your partition key, your data is actually being sorted by the token of id, not the values themselves:

```
cqlsh:testid> SELECT id,n,p,q,token(id) FROM table;

 id | n | p | q    | system.token(id)
----+---+---+------+----------------------
  5 | 1 | 2 |    4 | -7509452495886106294
 10 | 2 | 4 |    3 | -6715243485458697746
 11 | 1 | 2 | null | -4156302194539278891
```

Because of this, you don't have any control over how the partition key is sorted.

In order to sort your data by id, you need to make id a clustering column rather than a partition key.  Your data will still need a partition key, however, and this will always be sorted by token.

If you decide to make id a clustering column, you will need to specify that you want a descending order in your order by statement

```
CREATE TABLE clusterTable (
          ... partition type, //partition key with a type to be specified
          ... id INT,
          ... n INT,
          ... p INT,
          ... q INT,
          ... PRIMARY KEY((partition),id))
          ... WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id DESC);
```

This link is very helpful in discussing how ordering works in Cassandra: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order

Comment: Is it work ? SELECT * 
FROM clusterTable 
WHERE id IN ( 11,10,5) and results should be in same order as given..

Comment: It depends on what your partition key is.  IN does not specify the order of your results, it only states which results you want to see in the table.

Comment: is there any way without clustering order we can sort table data ?